# Datatable ajax.reload() with rowGroup

Tags: ajax, datatables

I want to refresh datatable and stay in current page using ajax.reload(null, false) but its not affect because im using rowGroup. Anyone knows how to handle this things ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: For your specific question, please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]. This should include the _minimal_ code and data (formatted as text, not screenshots) to recreate your issue. You should also show the text of any error messages (e.g. from the browser console), together with a description of what happens and what you want to happen (I am not sure what "_its not affect_" means, exactly).